Why Can't configure Find xrandr.pc?
I am compiling fvwm3 from source on Debian 12 bookworm. I "cd" to the source directory and run "./configure --enable-golang"
All is well until xrandr cannot be found, even though it is installed.
config.log 
configure:8877: checking for xrandr >= 1.5
configure:8884: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "xrandr >= 1.5"
Package xrandr was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xrandr.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'xrandr', required by 'virtual:world', not found
configure:8887: $? = 1
configure:8901: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "xrandr >= 1.5"
Package xrandr was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xrandr.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'xrandr', required by 'virtual:world', not found
configure:8904: $? = 1
configure:8918: result: no
Package 'xrandr', required by 'virtual:world', not found
configure:8935: error: *** XRandR not found.  Install its header files. ***

$ /usr/bin/xrandr --version
xrandr program version 1.5.1
Server reports RandR version 1.6

Thank you for your guidance!


$ /usr/bin/xrandr --version

That's not what the configure script is looking for! It's looking for a .pc file that lets it link to the "libxrandr" library – not for the command-line tool.
It could very well be that those come in separate packages, and indeed on Debian they nearly always do – it splits up everything into e.g. a "library" package, a "tools" package, a "development files" package, etc. Things like *.h and *.pc files are only required while compiling software, so they're left out of the standard installation.
In this case the development-related files for xrandr are in the libxrandr-dev package. You can always try lib<name>-dev first, and if that doesn't work, then use apt-file to search the index of all files found in all packages:
# apt install apt-file
# apt update
# apt-file search xrandr.pc


Thank you, grawity_u1686!  "sudo apt install libxrandr-dev" worked for me! The xrandr.pc file landed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/, and the configure utility was looking in /usr/share/pkgconfig/. You could copy the file, or, add the first path to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH envirronment variable.  The former worked for me.  Marked as solved.

Wait, why was the configure utility looking there at all?... It is supposed to just run the OS-provided pkg-config program, which would already know where to look (i.e. the Debian-provided pkg-config knows that its files are in /usr/lib/$arch)
